# Convergence of function of stochastic processes

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, limits-and-convergence, limit-theorems

Let $X_t$ be a fixed cadlag semi-martingale and $J_n$ be a fixed sequence of functions from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which are twice continuously differentiable.  If $J_n$ converge pointwise to the function $J$ which itself is a.e. differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^d$ (wrt to the Lebesgue measure-zero sets) and *not* differentiable everywhere; then under what non-trivial conditions on $J_n$ does
$$
J_n(X_t) \to J(X_t),
$$ 
in the Skorohod topology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the definition of Skorokhod topology,  for the $J_n(X_t)\to J(X_t)$ in Skorokhod topology,
it  suffices to suppose that
$$  \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{\|x\|\le a}|J_n(x)-J(x)|=0, \qquad \forall a>0.$$ 
i.e. $J_n $ convergence to $J$ uniformly in every compact set.

Comment: Could you provide a reference also, please?  I'm guessing somewhere in Jacod and Shryev's book:
http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540439325

Comment: @CSA Thank you for your reply. The definition of Skorokhod topology could refer to the Jacod & Shiryaev's book you mentioned or Billinsley's book: *Convergence of Probability Measures*. To prove $J_n(X_t)\to J(X_t)$ is just to verify according the definition.